# How do i add a hashtag to to Facebook button share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

How do i add a hashtag to to Facebook button share...

Please to understand it better click the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaSas.png)

Answer (score 5):

Using the facebook sdk you can add the `hashtag` parameter to the object.

`document.getElementById('share-facebook-btn').onclick = function() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        hashtag: '#thisisahashtag'
        href: 'https://example.com',
    }, function(response){});
}`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: Worth mentioning that this works using the URL redirect version of the dialog, too - in that case you just have to take care to properly URL-encode the hashtag, so `hashtag=%23foobar`

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
This answer is outdated, Facebook has since changed their policy (in this specific regard, suggesting a hashtag) - see Andrew's answer for details on the way to do this.

---

You simply don’t, because you are **not allowed** to.

See [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy#control), 2.3:

> *“Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.”*

---

If the *user* wants the message to include a hashtag, then the *user* has to type it in by him-/herself.

Comment: Immediately after the end of this quote it continues with: "You may use our Share Dialogs to prefill a single hashtag in a post, but don't prefill any content a person or business didn't create via the API."  *This is probably an update to the policy and not a mistake by CBroe*

Comment: @AndrewM you're right, they added that a couple of month after my answer  - http://www.webpronews.com/facebook-announces-ways-share-engage-2016-04/ Can't keep track of & update everything on here unfortunately, so your answer documenting the current state is more than welcome ;-)